# Possible to make child class instantiated only via static Properties

Tags: c#, class

Let's say I have the following  class:

```
public class Gender
{
    public readonly string Name { get; set;}
    public readonly char Abbreviation { get; set;} 
    public readonly string ChildName { get; set;}
    public readonly int Number { get; set;}

    public static Gender Male = new Gender { Name = "Male", Abbreviation = 'M', Number = 1, ChildName = "Boy" };
    public static Gender Female = new Gender { Name = "Female", Abbreviation = 'F', Number = 2, ChildName = "Girl" };
    public static Gender Unknown = new Gender { Name = "Unknown", Abbreviation = 'U', Number = 0, ChildName = "Unknown" };
}
```

How can I make it illegal to instantiate the Gender class by any other means besides

`Gender MyGender = Gender.Male`

thus making

```
Gender Spaghetti = new Gender{Name = "Spaghetti", Abbreviation = 'S', Number = 123, ChildName = "Angel Hair" }
```

throw an error at compile time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give it a single private constructor:

```
public class Gender
{
    // ...

    private Gender() {  }
}
```

Normally if no constructor is defined then the compiler creates a "default constructor" which has no parameters.  But if you define one, there's no default.  And if that one is private, nothing outside of that class can call it.  So nothing can build an instance of `Gender` except for `Gender` itself.

Answer (score 8):

Add `private` constructor to `Gender` class:

```
public class Gender
{
    public readonly string Name { get; set;}
    public readonly char Abbreviation { get; set;} 
    public readonly string ChildName { get; set;}
    public readonly int Number { get; set;}

    private Gender()
    {
    }

    public static Gender Male = new Gender { Name = "Male", Abbreviation = 'M', Number = 1, ChildName = "Boy" };
    public static Gender Female = new Gender { Name = "Female", Abbreviation = 'F', Number = 2, ChildName = "Girl" };
    public static Gender Unknown = new Gender { Name = "Unknown", Abbreviation = 'U', Number = 0, ChildName = "Unknown" };
}
```

You can add `readonly` to `Male`/`Female`/`Unknown` declaration too, to make following code impossible:

```
Gender.Male = Gender.Female;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the constructor private. This is how it would be used in SingleTon pattern.

Comment: No, it's not called singleton but is being used in singleton.

Comment: This is *not* a singleton.  There is more than one instance of the class.